# why this parse from string to DateTime fails in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a DateTime `eventDate` field in my Mysql table which I compose from the inputs when I insert it in db:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?eventDate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEventDate.Text + " " + txtEventTime.Text,
                "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and is saved nice:

> 2011-05-05 10:20:00

Now, when I read it from DB I want to split it but it fails if I do like this:

```
txtEventDate.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(Reader.GetValue(7).ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date.ToShortDateString();
txtEventTime.Text = DateTime.ParseExact(Reader.GetValue(7).ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay.ToString();
```

saying that:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Do you see any issue? I cannot figure out where I am wrong...

Comment: Are you storing the date as string in that database? If not, there is no need to parse the date when you read it from the database as it is already a date. Just cast it to a `DateTime` from the object returned by `reader.GetValue(..)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems superfluous to convert it to a string and parse it as a datetime and this may introduce problems with enexpected date formats.

If you have a `Datetime` in the database you could also do

```
  txtEventDate.Text = Reader.GetDatetime(7).ToShortDateString();
  txtEventTime.Text = Reader.GetDatetime(7).TimeOfDay().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

To format DateTime try something like this...

```
DateTime date = Reader.GetDateTime(7);
txtEventDate.Text = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
txtEventTime.Text = date.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the right format. That may be:

```
yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss
```